# how to change cwd with lineEdit input in pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, string, pyqt5

I want to change the cwd with a `lineEdit` input

basically type in the new path and changethe cwd with click on the button

```
# widgets
self.speicherort_input = qtw.QLineEdit()
self.speicherort_button = qtw.QPushButton("Speicherort_bestaetigen")


# signal
self.speicherort_button.clicked.connect(self.set_newpath)


# function
    def set_newpath(self):
        neuer_speicherort = self.speicherort_input.text()
        os.system('cd' + neuer_speicherort) # how to change variable to raw string ?
```

how can I change the input string into a raw string to change the cwd ?

I changed the function to convert the lineEditt_input into a raw string

```
neuer_speicherort = self.speicherort_input.text()

        raw_string = r"{}".format(neuer_speicherort)

        os.chdir(raw_string)
```

but the command did not get executed

Comment: change `os.system('cd' + neuer_speicherort)` to `os.chdir(neuer_speicherort)`

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: (https://gist.github.com/JosephCurvin/ad13a046e662ae0edb87a596da247d2b)

Comment: here is the git I found the `setWorkingDirectory` method and implemented it, but got no results so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tru it

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(700, 410)

        speicherort_label = qtw.QLabel("welcher Speicherort")

        self.speicherort_input = qtw.QLineEdit()
        self.speicherort_button = qtw.QPushButton("Speicherort_bestaetigen")
        self.check_cwd_button = qtw.QPushButton("Check cwd")
        layout1 = qtw.QFormLayout()

        self.setLayout(layout1)
        layout2 = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        layout2.addWidget(self.speicherort_input)
        layout2.addWidget(self.speicherort_button)
        layout1.addRow(speicherort_label, layout2)
        layout1.addRow(self.check_cwd_button)

        self.show()

        # funktionen
        self.speicherort_button.clicked.connect(self.changecwd)
        self.check_cwd_button.clicked.connect(self.printcwd)


    def changecwd(self):
        neuer_speicherort = self.speicherort_input.text()

#        raw_string = r"{}".format(neuer_speicherort)
#        new_process = qtc.QProcess()
#        new_process.setWorkingDirectory(raw_string)

        os.chdir(neuer_speicherort)                               # +++

    def printcwd(self):
        print(os.getcwd())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I tryed to reinvent the wheel with my function